# Unnamed member access?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand this piece of C++ code from a text book:

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct Buffer {
  using value_type = T;
  constexpr int size() { return N; }
  T[N];
  // ...
};
```

It demonstrates stack allocation of the `T[N]` array, but the array is not named. Later in the text this declaration is made:

```
Buffer<int,10> buf;
```

but it's not clear how to access the array buried inside this struct. Does the `//...` have to include some accessors or is there some implicit facility of the language that can be used to get at the `ints[10]` that live within buf?

Comment: What compiler did you try it with? [GCC in C++11 mode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57f911f57faffa15) gives "error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token"

Comment: I guess that answers it, it must be a typo in the text.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an implementation question that doesn't meet Stack Overflow's quality standards for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there some mistake, code does not even compile. So correct code would be like

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct Buffer {
using value_type = T;
constexpr int size() { return N; }
T b[N];
// ...
};
```

Edit: I tested it using gnu gcc 4.7.1 compiler in c++11 mode.

Comment: then the array could be accessed via buf.b[]